# How do I change the label separator for marginfigure in Tufte Book/Handout?

Tags: floats, captions, tufte

I'm trying to use the caption package to do this and I've used the following code, but it's still not giving me a period as a label separator. How can I go about fixing this? Here's what I have:

```
    \documentclass[english,dotinlabels,nohyper,notoc]{tufte-handout}
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=simple, labelsep = period}
    \captionsetup[marginfigure]{labelformat=simple, labelsep = period}

    \begin{document}

    \section{test}

    \begin{figure}
    \caption{erere}
    \end{figure}

    \vspace{20pt}

    this is a test

    \begin{marginfigure}
    \caption{rerweaere}
    \end{marginfigure}

    \end{document}
```

As indicated below, it works for figure, but not margin figure:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine `marginfigure` to include the change in the caption formatting:

```
\documentclass[english,dotinlabels,nohyper,notoc]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=simple, labelsep = period}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{marginfigure}[1][-1.2ex]%
  {\begin{@tufte@margin@float}[#1]{figure}%
    \captionsetup{labelformat=simple, labelsep = period}}
  {\end{@tufte@margin@float}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{test}

\begin{figure}
\caption{erere}
\end{figure}
\vspace{20pt}
this is a test

\begin{marginfigure}
\caption{rerweaere}
\end{marginfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As a side note, `openany` and `a5paper` are not supported class options with this document class.

Comment: Thanks. This worked perfectly. I've edited my code to remove the unsupported class options.

Comment: @EdwinMontufar You're welcome! You should also consider [`the answer`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78493/3954) given by the current  maintainer of the class.

Answer (score 3):

The Tufte-LaTeX classes don't play very nicely with the `caption` package, currently.

The easiest solution is to redefine the `\@caption` command that is defined by the Tufte-LaTeX classes.  In the preamble of your document, add the following code:

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{%
  \par
  \addcontentsline{\csname ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}%
    {\protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
  \begingroup
    \@parboxrestore
    \if@minipage
      \@setminipage
    \fi
    \@tufte@caption@font\@tufte@caption@justification
    \noindent\csname fnum@#1\endcsname. \ignorespaces#3\par% changed : to .
  \endgroup}
\makeatother
```

The example that you provided also has centered captions (as a by-product of using the `caption` package) instead of the ragged-right captions normally found in Tufte-style documents.

As [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3954/gonzalo-medina) [mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78491/80), the `openany` and `a5paper` options are ignored by the Tufte-LaTeX classes.

Comment: Thank you. This worked as well. I'll keep this handy in case 'caption' doesn't work right. As for the centered captions, this doesn't occur when I actually have an image embedded.

Comment: It's really nice to know you're around (and sorry for not noticing it before). I really like the the features provided by the Tufte-LaTeX classes!

Comment: @godbyk I'd like to thank you for maintaining this wonderful class.

Comment: @EdwinMontufar: When I ran a test with images here, the captions were centered. But if it looks okay on your end, then feel free to stick with the `caption` package.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Thanks! I'm hoping to do some more development work on the T-L classes over the next few months (as I'll be using it to write my dissertation).